# AngularJS cannot execute Controller method in IE and Edge just for clicking refresh button

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, page-refresh

I am using angularJS and want to execute the function when page change such as change the route and refresh the page. I already added the code in the `customfactory.js` as below:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module("app")
    .factory("RuntimeFactory", ["HttpFactory", RuntimeFactory]);

  function RuntimeFactory(HttpFactory) {
    var services = {};
    services.run = function (data) {
        var url = "home/run"
        var data = {
            "name": "Petet"
        };

        return HttpFactory.send("POST", url, null, data);
    };
  }
```

In HomeController Run method:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public JsonStatusCodeResult Run(String data) {
  //... some code.
}
```

For changing the page, all browser can be successful to call Run method in Controller.cs, however **IE and Edge does not working when click the browser refresh button**. In debug mode, after execute `return HttpFactory.send("POST", url, null, data);`  then the browser refreshed, does not execute the Run method.

Comment: What your IE and Edge browser version? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: IE11 , there are no any error. I updated my case.